# SQL query with inner join, acos and radians translation to Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join, radians

I have to translate a query from SQL to Access query.
This is the SQL query:

```
SELECT ABS(timestampdiff(minute,p.tempo,p2.tempo)) as tempoDifferita, 
       ABS(6372.7954775979997  (Acos( Sin(RADIANS(p.lat))  Sin(RADIANS(p2.lat)) + 
       Cos(RADIANS(p.lat))  Cos(RADIANS(p2.lat)) 
       Cos(ABS(RADIANS(p.lon) - RADIANS(p2.lon)))))*1000) AS distanza,
       p.idutenza,p2.idutenza as idutenza2, p.tempo, p2.tempo as tempo2, 
       p.lon,p.lat, p2.lon as lon2, p2.lat as lat2, p.velocita,
       p2.velocita as velocita2, p.indirizzo,p2.indirizzo as indirizzo2,
       p.nsat, p2.nsat as nsat2, p.direzione, p2.direzione as direzione2, 
       p.flags, p2.flags as flags2 
FROM punti as p  
INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT  FROM punti AS p2 
      WHERE p2.idutenza =  1 AND p2.tempo>=#2017-01-31 09:15:20# 
       AND p2.tempo<=#2017-05-24 13:01:31# AND p2.flags&1=1 
       AND NOT (p2.Lat=0 AND p2.Lon=0) ) as p2 
WHERE p.idutenza = 2 AND p.tempo>=#2017-01-31 09:15:20# 
  AND p.tempo<=#2017-05-24 13:01:31#
  AND p.flags&1=1 AND NOT (p.Lat=0 AND p.Lon=0) 
  AND ABS(timestampdiff(minute,p.tempo,p2.tempo))<= 60 
  AND ABS(6372.7954775979997  (Acos( Sin(RADIANS(p.lat))  
      Sin(RADIANS(p2.lat)) + Cos(RADIANS(p.lat))  
      Cos(RADIANS(p2.lat)) * Cos(ABS(p.lon - p2.lon))))*1000) <= 500
```

It works perfectly in MySQL.

In Access it gives error in the `INNER JOIN`, Acos and Radians and really I don't know how to translate everything in order to work with Access.
Someone could help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: No two databases (MySQL, MS Access, SQLite, Postgres, SQL Server, DB2, Oracle, etc.) can easily have their SQL syntax translated as dialects differ. Simply, there are no trig functions in Access SQL.

Comment: You will need to interface to VBA if you use MSAccess.exe but such a query will not work via ODBC. Consider using a [pass-through query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/303968/how-to-create-an-sql-pass-through-query-in-access) to MySQL in Access and use its exact dialect.